# How to expose promise inside function to outside in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have promise in Typescript like:

```
dbManager: Promise<EntityManager> = createConnection({
  ...
}).then( connection => return connection.manager);
```

when I use it in another file, it should do like:

```
dbManager.then((db)=>db.save(Entity))
```

What I want to invoke function like:

```
dbManager.save(Entity);
```

How to expose the inner function to outside?

Comment: To make something available, whatever it is, you `return` it, `export` it, or assign it to a property on some accessible object. It depends on the context, and that context is missing here.

Comment: sorry change return from connection to connection.manager